# What is the reason for moving the instance variable into an abstract class in the decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

In the book "Head first design patterns (2014, 2nd edition)" in the chapter about the decorator pattern the authors take the instance variable `Beverage beverage` from the 4 condiment classes (Milk, Mocha, Soy, Whip) and put it into the abstract class `CondimentDecorator`. (see page 110, the solution to the `getSize()`-question)

```
public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage{
  public Beverage beverage;
  public abstract String getDescription();

  public Size getSize(){
    return beverage.getSize();
  }
}
```

What is the reason for moving the instance variable `Beverage beverage` from the condiment-classes to the abstract class `CondimentDecorator`?

Do they do it in order to save some code lines, since now the condiments dont need to declare their own instance variable since they inherit it from the abstract class?

**UML diagram for the coffe shop BEFORE they move the instance variable:**

[image: UML for coffee shop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More importantly than reducing code size, moving the `Beverage` instance into the `CondimentDecorator` guarantees that every `CondimentDecorator` actually has a `Beverage`. Otherwise, someone could implement a `CondimentDecorator` without a `Beverage`, which wouldn't make much sense.

Composition (rather than inheritance) is the heart of the Decorator Pattern, so it's important to guarantee that every decorator actually composes (decorates) its intended target.

Comment: So it's not mandatory to put the `Beverage`-instance into the `CondimentDecorator`, but helps to keep track of possible errors?

Comment: Yes, the pattern has the same effect regardless of where the `Beverage` is decorated.

Answer (score 0):

`Design Pattern : Decorator` helps in adding/removing responsibilities from a class dynamically.

Now,  given Beverage can be something like:

- Caffe Mocha, soy milk, no whipped cream.
- Caffe Mocha, no soy milk, with whipped cream.
- .. etc ..

If you see a composite/final `Beverage` then its a combination of other primitive `Beverages` namely `Milk`, `Mocha`, `Soy`, `Whip`. Other way to look at a given `Beverage` is: We can *add* or *remove* some ingredient from the base `Beverage` to create the final `Beverage`.

Now, if you try to create a `Beverage`, then this `Beverage` should be able to add/remove ingredients(read other `Beverages`) dynamically depending upon the kind of `Beverage` order received in a hotel.

So, let's try to create a `Beverage: "Caffe Mocha, soy milk, with whipped cream"`. Here, our base ingredient is `Mocha`. Now, lets start with ingredient `Soy` milk and to this `Soy` we will add or `Whip` the cream. Finally, we will add this `Soy` milk `Whip`ped with cream to our base ingredient `Mocha`.

`Soy -> Whip`

`Mocha -> Soy -> Whip`

So, we started with a kind of `Beverage` and then to this `Beverage` added another kind of `Beverage` and then added this composite `Beverage` to base `Beverage`.

So, it makes sense to **make provision** in ingredients so that other ingredients can be added or removed from them as and when required. And therefore, instead of keeping `Beverage` pointer/instance inside every concrete ingredients, its better to keep the `Beverage` pointer inside the base class so that all the derived class can get the pointer automatically. And then using this pointer, every derived class can add other ingredients and create a new component/`Beverage`. This is the whole point of `Decorator`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of this pattern on Wiki:

> Decorator (also known as Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Adapter pattern) is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.

The purpose of Decorator is to add behavior to an individual object. Say if you have an AuthenticationService object that has method called authenticate() with no logging support. One day, your customer ask you to add logging after user is authenticated without breaking or modifying current structure and the service. Then Decorator is useful in this case. You can simply define a new LoggingSupportAuthenticationService as derivative of AuthenticationService and override authenticate(), then inside the function, delegate authentication to the wrapped AuthenticationService instance and then put one more logging statement at the end of the method.

I'm not having any code editor here so you can read this article for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178467(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec3